# Не получается парсить JSON

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

Есть Веб Сервис написанный на Jax-rs 2.0. С сайта отправляется JSON на веб сервер с строковыми данными и одним изображением. Веб сервер принимает этот запрос, отправляет входящий поток, что распарсить его, и в этот момент Веб Сервис зависает. Вот метод веб сервиса,когда происходит парсинг JSON'a

```
public Post generatePost(InputStream io) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Saving new post.");
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println("OLOLO");
    post = objectMapper.readValue(io, Post.class);
    System.out.println(post);
    saveImage(post.getImage());
    System.out.println("OLOLOLOLO 3");
    return post;
}
```

А вот то что я вижу в логах сервера:

```
00:04:30,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "lya-mur.core2.war" (runtime-name : "lya-mur.core2.war")
00:04:30,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
00:04:30,529 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
00:04:30,530 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
00:04:30,531 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 11.0.0.CR1 (WildFly Core 3.0.1.Final) started in 73482ms - Started 633 of 864 services (371 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
00:04:40,293 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Saving new post.
00:04:40,564 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) OLOLO
```

Из за чего может быть такой ступор?

Comment: Где он у вас зависает? Не вижу никакого зависания

Comment: @Roman Danilo, в логах видно, что доходит только до второго sout, а в коде их 4. В инпут стриме есть данные, но он их не считывает в строке "post = objectMapper.readValue();".